# In Ubuntu, how might I from the terminal open application only if it's not already running?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm using a basic script to open up the apps I need for development and I have to open an editor, but only if it's not already running.

How can I first determine if sublime is up before running the application as follows:

```
subl <filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can always determine it running by 'ps ax|grep', right?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got one solution:

```
SERVICE=$1
if [ `pgrep $SERVICE` ]
  then
    echo "$SERVICE is running."
  else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at `ps`?

```
if [[ $(ps -e | grep "the thing you want") -ne 0 ]]
#checks if there is anything returned
then
  subl <filename>
fi
```

This correctness will be based on how "exact" you search...